# В чем заключается ошибка в int?

Tags: c

Начал изучать Си. Столкнулся с тем что компилятор постоянно ругается на не инициализированную переменную int. А когда вставляю преобразование из char в int, через функцию atoi, то компилятор молчит.
Такой код компилятор не пускает:

```
int num;
scanf_s("%d", num);
```

Выдает ошибку с4700.
А такой пускает:

```
char a[10];
int num;
scanf_s("%s", a, 10);
num=atoi(a);
```

Почему так? Компилятор MVS 2015.

Comment: "Ошибка в int" заключается в том, что там требуется не `int`, а `int *`.

Answer (score 3):

Потому что так -

```
int num;
scanf_s("%d", num);
```

это неверно.

```
int num;
scanf_s("%d", &num);
```

Иначе вы пытаетесь записать целое число по адресу, который лежит в `num`. А поскольку там лежит мусор - компилятор пытается вам помочь. Жаль, что вы его еще не научились слышать, но со временем опыт придет...

Во втором варианте нигде не используется *значение неинициализированной переменной*, так что и предупреждать компилятору не о чем.